# Why can't I code a button using the variable I declared for it but I can use the button without declaring any variable in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm working on a project in Visual Basic, a Windows Form App. I created a button (and I called it button0) and while trying to handle the click event for it, I declared a variable for it like so:

```
Public Class Project
    Dim txtAnswer As String
    Public Sub button0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button0.Click
        txtAnswer = answerBox.Text
        If txtAnswer.Length = 0 Then
            txtAnswer = "0"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But, the text box doesn't output '0' whenever I click the button. But, when I try this, it does:

```
Public Class Project
    Public Sub button0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button0.Click
        If answerBox.Text.Length = 0 Then
            answerBox.Text= "0"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Whenever I declare a variable, it doesn't work, but when I don't, it does work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `txtAnswer` is not a _reference_ to the `Text` property, it's just a variable. If you chagne `txtAnswer` you only change the value of that variable, not of the `answerBox.Text` property.

Comment: Strings are copied, not referenced. This mean when you do txtAnswer = answerBox.Text, then txtAnswer will be a copy separate to the .Text property. Just set it back at the end: answerBox.Text= txtAnswer

Comment: In your first code example your variable  `txtAnswer`holds a copy of the text from `answerBox.Text`. All your changes are on the variable with the copy, not on the textbox. You should write the value of the variable `txtAnswer`back to `answerBox.Text`

Answer (score 1):

While David and Bryant1003 have correct answers, the final code is a bit round-a-bout. In the interests of tighter coding:

```
Public Class Project
    Public Sub button0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button0.Click
        answerBox.Text = if(answerBox.Text.Length = 0, "0", answerBox.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The local variable is only used in the previous examples as a temporary holder. The `If` statement is valid in later `.Net` versions and not in `VBA`. In this instance, it is safe to use `IIf` as well.

Of course, if you do further operations on answerBox.Text, you may consider assigning to a temporary variable. But whether that is required will depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`txtAnswer` and `answerBox.Text` are not mirroring each other, as you're thinking they are.

In your first example, you're setting your variable to store the value in the textbox. Then, if the length of the string is 0, you're setting it to store "0". This doesn't then set `answerBox.Text` to *also* be "0".

Whereas, in your second example, you're updating the textbox to display "0", rather than an unconnected variable.

If you want to use a variable as in your first example, you'd need to do

```
Public Class Project
Dim txtAnswer As String

  Public Sub button0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button0.Click

      txtAnswer = answerBox.Text

      If txtAnswer.Length = 0 Then
          txtAnswer = "0"
      End If

      answerBox.Text = txtAnswer
  End Sub
End Class
```

You can just expect the `TextBox.Text` property to update automatically because you updated  a variable. You need to tell it to use the value in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not assigning the value back into "answerBox".

The variable is populated (read: copied) into txtAnswer on the first line of your sub. As this is copied in, you need to put the string back into the the textbox after you've finished your processing of it. See the code below with the added line;

```
Public Class Project
    Dim txtAnswer As String
    Public Sub button0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button0.Click
        txtAnswer = answerBox.Text
        If txtAnswer.Length = 0 Then
            txtAnswer = "0"
        End If
        ' The below line puts the value from the variable txtAnswer back into the textbox
        answerBox.Text = txtAnswer
    End Sub
End Class
```